# Touchpad on Gateway LT2802u Netbook doesn't work

Tags: 11.10, touchpad, synaptic

I installed Xubuntu Oneiric on a Netbook. The Synaptic Device is recognized by the system and back in Lucid it worked. But now it won't work anymore.

`grep -B 5 mouse /proc/bus/input/devices1`

gave me

```
    I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=0007 Version=01b1
    N: Name="SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad"
    P: Phys=isa0060/serio2/input0
    S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio2/input/input9
    U: Uniq=
    H: Handlers=mouse0 event9
```

Please help me :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a terminal window:

```
synclient TouchpadOff=1
```